# How can I save an html file and remove script and unwanted tag when dowloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I have an [html](/questions/tagged/html) file with lots of tags with `contenteditable="true"` attribute. I also added a lot of jquery/js inside.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Let user modify the content --> ok with `contenteditable` attribute
2. Let user download the modified file --> ok with the snippet below
3. When clicking on download button, remove all content between "Delete" and "Delete End" comments, and also remove all `"contenteditable="true"` attributes --> not ok

I also found this download snippet which is drastically shorter than the one I use in the following snippet, but don't know which is better, safer?

```
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="index.html">Download</a>
```

Here is an example of my file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!--Delete Start-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <!--Delete End-->
  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important;background-color: #F2F2F2;">
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <p style="margin: 0 0 8px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <!--Delete Start-->
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="add content">
    <input type="button" id="del" value="remove content">
  </div>
  <!--Delete End-->


  <!--Delete Start-->
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="donwload-link" onClick="myFunction()">download html content</a>
  </div>
  <!--Delete End-->


  <!--Delete Start-->
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
      download(content, "index", "html")
    }

    function download(content, fileName, fileType) {
      var link = document.getElementById("donwload-link");
      var file = new Blob([content], {
        type: "html"
      });
      var donwloadFile = fileName + "." + fileType;
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      link.download = donwloadFile
    }
  </script>
  <!--Delete End-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Refresh the page ?

Comment: I didn't understand your answer..

Comment: If you want reset all page (so all element with contenteditable)  after download code, why don't refresh the page directly instead of delete html of every elements?

Comment: maybe I wasn't enough clear..In fact I want, when I download the  html file to get the file without contenteditable attributes, and without the script..refreshing the page don't remove html..I don't really understand what you're meaning.. I don't want to reset the page, but remove specific attribute from the html once it's downloaded

Comment: Was unclear, can you create a complete example with html too ?

Comment: no because the file is too big..it's a simple html file with script in the bottom (function to add remove blocks) and those contenteditable attributes, nothing special. I can download it but don't know how to mix a function to remove attributes and scripts with the download function. Thanks for you help

Comment: Just remove them before downloading, and you don't need to paste in your entire page, only a relevant minimized example.

Comment: ***The problem I have is that if I simply use removeAttribute on click, it will remove attribute on the browser but not on the dowloaded file.*** because you will still download the file, what happens if you download a stripped off version saved to a variable?

Comment: thank you very much for taking time on this..I simplified my question and added an example code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `class` attribute to something like `delete` and use [`querySelectorAll(".delete, script")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through these elements and use [`element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) in your `clean()` function in addition to removing the `contentEditable` from the other elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<!--Delete Start-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!--Delete End-->

<p contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<!--Delete Start-->
<div class="delete">
  <input type="button" id="add" value="add content">
  <input type="button" id="del" value="remove content">
</div>
<!--Delete End-->

<!--Delete Start-->
<div class="delete">
  <a href="#" id="download-link" onClick="myFunction()">download html content</a>
</div>
<!--Delete End-->

<!--Delete Start-->
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    clean();
    var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    download(content, "index", "html");
  }

  function clean() {
    var contentToDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".delete, script");
    var editableContent = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
    for (var i = 0; i < editableContent.length; i++) {
      editableContent[i].removeAttribute('contenteditable');
    }
    contentToDelete.forEach((element) => element.remove());
  }

  function download(content, fileName, fileType) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {
      type: "html"
    });
    var downloadFile = fileName + "." + fileType;
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    link.download = downloadFile;
    link.click();
  }
</script>
<!--Delete End-->
```

Comment: OH nice phentnil !! thank you so much !I had the idea that I had to use a regex and I wanted to avoid using classes but finally the result is exactly what I wanted. thank you very much because I was stuck!

Comment: Regex works well for many purposes. However, since there is a whole [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API) with loads of document manipulation methods, it's better to use some of those. Referencing elements that don't have classes or IDs is a bit tricky, so I felt that adding that in would simplify the problem a bit.

Comment: what you did solved my problem. In fact originally my file is composed of table, starting with tr. So adding classes seems difficult to me, and searching and deleting all the content between comments suits me more because there is a lot of content. I will try to start from your code to integrate a regex..but thanks a lot, you really helped me ! :)

Comment: That's true: if there's a lot of content, adding classes and IDs could be a lot of work. It just depends on which way provides the best/easiest solution for the long-term. If I have to replace large blocks of text/code, I try to write a regex to find and replace the specific blocks of text/code in my IDE.

Comment: yes, I updated my question with another solution I just found with a regex..it works pretty well but it's not perfect..a little more work and I think I'll get there! it's thanks to you, thank you again ; )